Should I store start time, end time, and days as separate fields or use a CRON expression in my database?
I am developing a scheduling feature in my application where users can set specific time ranges and days for recurring tasks. For example, a user might configure a task to run every Thursday and Friday from 15:00 to 16:00.
I need to store these schedules in my database and am debating between two approaches:

Storing start time, end time, and a list of days as separate fields.
Using a CRON expression to represent the schedule.

Here's a simplified version of the current approach using separate fields:

start_time: "15:00"
end_time: "16:00"
days: ["Thursday", "Friday"]

Alternatively, I could convert these schedules to a CRON expression in UTC:

CRON: "0 15 * * 4,5"

Considerations :

Time Zones: Users configure times in their local time zone, but the application needs to store and process these times in UTC - Maybe it is better to store it as UTC, right?

If a user change it's time zone, for example he moves from time zone A to B, I will have to update all it's schedules stored in database, because the time (15h-16h) should be the same.

Users have a date picker. it's easier for them to use date picker instead define a cron.


Questions:

Which approach is generally recommended for storing recurring schedules in a database?
Are there best practices or common patterns for handling such scheduling requirements?

Thank you a lot!

How are you going to query this database? e.g. would you ever have a query that says, "It's 6:39 on Friday, what events are going on right now?" How else might you query this?

Exactly! I will have a cron each x minutes that will request my database and ask all events that match my conditions based on hour range and day.
Now that you mention it, I don't know if a cron could answer my need for the “time range” part...
Using your example, if I define a range from 6 to 9, for example, and it's 6:39 am, then this respects the condition and my query will have a result. If I defined a range from 4 to 6, then no result.

A common way I've seen this done is to store the date & time that the event will next trigger. You can have a a tree-based index on this field in SQL. This allows you to quickly query for events which trigger in the next five minutes which have not already been handled. This allows you to tell which events in your database are irrelevant, without fetching them.

If I only store the date and time of the next event, once this event has been processed, how can I know the date of the next one?
I still have to store 3 fields, start time, end time, and the days involved, don't I?

Yes. The field I'm describing would be in addition to your other fields.

Ok! So every time I trigger an event, I calculate the date of the next event and store it in this new dedicated table?What happens if the user changes his timezone in the meantime? So I have to store the hours in local hours? (And I was going to store the timezone in the user table). I find this time management very complex .. :(
